# How to pass a jQuery variable to PHP code?

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I have reframed my Question:

I have a drop down box which is populated with a list of users.

```
    <a href="#" class="Share<?=$r['Form']['id'];?>">Share</a>
    <form action="/FormBuilder/index.php/forms/share/<?=$r['Form']['id']?>/<?=$userid?>" method="post" id="shareform<?=$r['Form']['id'];?>" class="shareform">
            <p>Select the users with whom you want to share the Form</p>
            <select id="userList" name="userList" multiple>
                    <?php foreach($users as $user){  ?>
                            <option value=<?=$user['User']['id'];?>><?=$user['User']['name'];?></option>        
                    <?php }?>
            </select> 
            <input type="submit" class="button" value="Share"/>
    </form>
```

When I select the user and give submit, the Form's access field in the database is updated to "Shared".

Now I need to display the Form name that has been shared in the home page of the user whom I selected. This is the code for displaying the Form names that have been marked as "shared".

```
    <?php if (!empty($formsShared)){   
    foreach ($formsShared as $shared): 
        echo $shared['Form']['name']; 
    endforeach; 
    }
    else{
        echo "There are no shared Forms !"; 
    }?>
```

I need to get the selected values in the drop down box, so that I can have another for loop to display the Shared form only in the selected users home page. How do I get the option:value?

Comment: why have you voted down the question? Have I asked something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will want to send them a PHP script using [AJAX](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post#urldatacallbacktype).

```
$.post("file.php", { data: selected_value[i] } );
```

and in your PHP script:

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
```

If the drop down is just one part of the form, then you create a hidden form field, with the value as *selected_value[i]*.

Answer (score 3):

Any time you want to get data from JavaScript back into PHP, you are looking at a request+response.

XHR would be the way to go.  You obviously aren't obligated to send back anything if all you're doing is receiving information or updating say...session state.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible within the page.  You need to submit in the form or pass it via an xhr post/get.

Then you could asses it in PHP via the regular parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to send them a PHP script using AJAX.

```
$.post("file.php", { data: selected_value[i] } );
```

And in your PHP script:

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
```

with this script, give me  a simple example valid.

thank you...